# How to create a new ImageData object independently?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I want to create a new ImageData object in code. If I have a `Uint8ClampedArray` out of which I want to make an image object, what is the best way to do it?

I guess I could make a new canvas element, extract its ImageData and overwrite its data attribute, but that seems like a wrong approach.

It would be great if I could use the ImageData constructor directly, but I can't figure out how to.

Comment: This seems to have inspired a fix to the spec to make it easier https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=24301

Comment: @Domenic ha ha, thanks for the link. I'm actually feeling rather proud now, although I know it isn't a big deal. But hey, a student's question leading to a revision of the spec isn't a small deal either.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is interesting problem... You can't just create `ImageData` object:

```
var test = new ImageData(); // TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

I have also tried:

```
var imageData= context.createImageData(width, height);
imageData.data = mydata; // TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of #<ImageData>
```

but as described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/ImageData) `data` property is readonly.

So I think the only way is to create object and set data property with iteration:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var imageData = canvas.getContext('2d').createImageData(width, height);
for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++){
    imageData.data[i] = myData[i];
}
```

**Update:**
I have discovered the `set` method in `data` property of ImageData, so solution is very simple:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var imageData = canvas.getContext('2d').createImageData(width, height);
imageData.data.set(myData);
```

Comment: where did you find `set`?  It's not mentioned in MDN

Comment: @programminginallston, ImageData's data is a Uint8ClampedArray :)

Comment: @twinlakes for futher reference on ImageData Uint8clampedarrays check [this](http://www.javascripture.com/Uint8ClampedArray).

Comment: This answer is the most upvoted but at the same time is outdated. Please check the other answers, in particular suggesting `ImageData` constructor - as for me that is better and way more concise.

Answer (score 12):

All modern browsers including Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Safari support the `ImageData` constructor. You can find its definition at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData).

You can use it like this:

```
let imgData1 = new ImageData(data, width, height);
let imgData2 = new ImageData(width, height);
```

For very old browsers you can create this constructor yourself:

```
function ImageData() {
    var i = 0;
    if(arguments[0] instanceof Uint8ClampedArray) {
        var data = arguments[i++];
    }
    var width = arguments[i++];
    var height = arguments[i];      
    
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
    if(data) imageData.data.set(data);
    return imageData;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ImageData` constructor is finally becoming available in Chrome and Firefox (see the compatibility table on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData.ImageData)). There are two forms:

```
var imageData = new ImageData(width, height);
```

and if you want to build an instance with a `UInt8ClampedArray` object `data`:

```
var imageData = new ImageData(data, width, height); // height is optional
```

For compatibility reasons, it's best to use `createImageData` via a canvas 2D context though, as demonstrated in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `createImageData()` method. But for this you need the context of an existing canvas.

```
var myImageData = context.createImageData(cssWidth, cssHeight);
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) for more information.